# Check/uncheck button not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
   <img  onClick="return chkall()" id="btnchkall" name="btnchkall" class="submit_button" value="Check All"  src="images/check_all.jpg">
<img  onClick="return unchkall()" id="btnunchkall" name="btnunchkall" class="submit_button" value="Uncheck All"  src="images/uncheck_all.jpg">

function chkall() {
//  var status=$('#btnchkall').val();

        $('input[name="checkbox[]"]').attr('checked', true);
                $('#btnchkall').css('display','none');
                $('#btnunchkall').css('display','block');
        //$('#btnchkall').attr('alt','uncheckall');
//      $('#btnchkall').attr('value','un check');

}

function unchkall(){

$('input[name="checkbox[]"]').attr('checked', false);
$('#btnchkall').css('display','block');
$('#btnunchkall').css('display','none');

}



  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="chech_box"  value="<?php echo $value->intstatusid;?>">
```

When the page is refreshed it is working one time....after that not working....

Comment: please explain little more

Comment: check it http://jsfiddle.net/5KQ6X/

Comment: not sure why you need to `return` in onClick for function that doesn't return anything(will return undefined)

Comment: i tried by removing the return()...still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function chkall() {

            $('.chech_box').attr('checked', true);                    

    }

    function unchkall(){

     $('.chech_box').attr('checked', false);    

    }
```

Comment: Thanks friend....i tried using your code...Check is working now...but uncheck is not working....

Comment: To uncheck, I would try with `$('.chech_box').removeAttr('checked')` rather than setting the checked attribute to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery 1.6+, you should use the new .prop() function:

$('.submit_button').prop('checked', true); 
$('.submit_button').prop('checked', false);

More here:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

```
#Display seleted news in text field
if not True in user_selection:
      text_box.insert(0.0, "you need to select at least one news. ")
else: 
     if user_selection[0]:
         text_box.insert(END, "you select Education_Family. ")
     if user_selection[1]:
         text_box.insert(END, "you select Politics. ")
     if user_selection[2]:
         text_box.insert(END, "you select Science_Environment. ")
     if user_selection[3]:
         text_box.insert(END, "you select entertainment_Arts. ")
```

[Screenshot of the code in action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgvt7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.